# Apple Product ID for Soomla

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, in-app-purchase, soomla

In Soomla(http://project.soom.la/), they have in-app purchase one liner that looks like this:

```
[StoreInventory buyItemWithItemId:@"[itemId]"]
```

However, i'm not sure whether the itemId is the same as the product id defined under iTunes Connect. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: what's stopping you from simply trying it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The itemId is not the store's productId.

itemId - a unique identifier of an every item defined in your virtual economy (internal use inside SOOMLA).
productId - a unique identifier of an every item defined in the App Store. You define it in the developer console.

When you buys something using StoreInventory, use the itemId.

Comment: They are not the same, you are supposed to define a soomla virtual good with title, description, itemId, and link it to a apple product id, in your own implementation of CCStoreAssets. However, I've been using the same string of itemId as the productId, there's no problem.